# C language factorial function

Tags: c, factorial

The code below is running wrong. If I give the function 4 value, it returns the number -861720576. Can you help?

```
#include <stdio.h>

int fact(int x)
{
        if (x<0)
        {
                return -1;
        }
        else if (x==0)
        {
                return 1;
        }
        else if (x==1)
        {
                return 1;
        }
        else
        {
                for (int i=2;i<x;i++)
                {
                        x*=i;
                }
                return x;
        }


}

int main()
{

        printf("%d",fact(4));
        return 0;
}
```

.................................

Comment: Use a separate variable to generate the result.

Comment: `i<x` - you are constantly increasing `x` inside the loop, so this condition is very broken

Comment: Instead, try `for (int i=x-1; i>1; i--) { x *= i; }`. That way the changing value of `x` has no effect on the loop exit condition.

Answer (score 1):

The loop termination condition is `i<x` but every time the loop runs, x is getting changed.  Note that the termination expression gets evaluated before each iteration of the loop so it will use the latest values of both `i` and `x`.

Answer (score 0):

at some point x will reach a number which isn't in the range of an integer. At that point x is gonna get messed up. Also your loop would be endless if x could reach any number.

Answer (score 0):

You're changing the value of x every time. Rather try this.

```
int final_val = x;
for (int i=2;i<x;i++)
{
    final_val *=i;
}
return final_val;
```